# Burning smell on power supply

Tags: power-supply

I opened my desktop and leave it until it boot. After few minutes, I logged-in my account and noticed that there is a burning smell on my computer. I immediately turned off my AVR thinking something might explode or fireup. It was already midnight so I left it unplugged.

The following day, I removed all the components to check where the burning smell came from. I started from the AVR, and it seems normal.

Then I tried powering up PSU alone (connecting green wire to black to turn it on) and noticed that the burning smell coming out from that component. I checked if there are signs of burn marks but I found nothing, it seems normal, no smoke coming out of the PSU.

Is there a way I could fix it or just a normal compressed air to clean it might repair my PSU? There are dust build up on the dust filter(pc case) and there is a minimal amount of dust inside my PSU.

My power supply is **Cougar SL 600** which I bought 3-4 years ago, out of warranty.

I usually leave my computer running overnight (9pm - 5am)

Comment: There's only one answer: replace the power supply - it's simply not worth the risk of running an unattended unit with any suspicion that it may be unsafe.

Comment: The magic smoke - it's gone; it won't come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with what AFH said, I wouldn’t recommend using your PSU anymore, especially if you were able to isolate this as the problem. Running a PSU that has a burning smell to it, even if you don’t notice any immediate performance issues, is not good practice.

If it isn’t smoking yet, you probably have an electrical burn-out which is causing the smell and not good to continue to run on. This can spread further and cause other components to be effected and possibly fail.

If 600W is what you require for your PC, grab a new one, from a trusted and reliable company (Corsair, EVGA, CoolerMaster, etc.) and power back up. You can grab 600w 80+ Bronze PSU’s for around $60. Definitely a component of your PC I wouldn’t go cheap on.